# if(boolean) always executed

Tags: java

Here's my code simplified

```
private static boolean isTrue()
{
    return false;
}


public void Update()
{
    if (isTrue())
        doSomething();
}
```

For some odd reason `doSomething()` gets always executed, no matter what `isTrue()` returns.
Why?

Edit: I had a semicolon somewhere off screen directly after closing the if statement like this:

```
if (false);
    doSomething();
```

Like this `doSomething()` gets executed always.

Comment: Did you try running the snippet you've posted? By the way, check that you don't have a `;` directly after the `if`.

Comment: That is too less a code to be solved.

Comment: `define(false, true)` ;-)

Comment: make sure you dont habe something like `if (IsTrue());`. Note the semicolon

Comment: Use curly braces for your `if` statement (and anywhere else that you might be skipping them) so you can be sure your logic actually looks like you intended it. Cheating on curly braces (in Java) is a flow-control nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: And please respect the Java naming conventions: `isTrue()`, `doSomething()`

Comment: Use: `ClassName.StaticMethodName()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> For some odd reason DoSomething() gets always executed, no matter what
>   IsTrue returns. Why?

This can be only if one or more of the following occurs:

- There are other threads calling `doSomething()`.
- You have `;` after `if`.  ✓
- You're calling it from somewhere else.
- This is not the code.
- The day has arrived, computers control the world.

Important note, more than the question: Please follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

---

After your edit, I'll explain why it's always executed.

It's simply because

```
if(something);
{
   System.out.println("I'll be always printed!");
}
```

Is equivalent to

```
if(something) { }
{
   System.out.println("I'll be always printed!");
}
```

It's a good practice to **always** have `{` and `}`, even if the body of the `if` includes only one statement, it's clearer and will help you to avoid possible bugs in the future, like @GrijeshChauhan mentioned, if you want to add lines in the future.

Comment: Yes. Somebody has a great sense of humor meddling with my code. That's a hard one to catch ^^

Comment: "The day has arrived, computers control the world." - I didn't thought about that until now:)

Comment: @maronum I would like to add in your last line:  `"even if the body of the if includes only one statement."` + `" The reason: Should you later decide to add a statement to the body, you don't have to remember to add the braces to complete the compound statement, hence it is always safe to use brackets even for single statment."`  Add in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

public class Main {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Update();
}
private static boolean IsTrue()
{
    return false;
}


public static void Update()
{
    if (IsTrue())
        DoSomething();
}
public static void DoSomething()
{
   System.out.println("In DoSomething");
}
```

}

This peice of code is working as designed. if the IsTrue() method retruns true then it will print "In DoSomething".